# Как заменить фразу в контенте кроме подписей внутри картинок?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, img

Есть сайт на **wordpress** и необходимость по всему сайту найти фразу текста и обрамить его в тег `span` c классом.

Делаю вот так:

```
function replace_content($content)
{
$content = str_replace('Company Name', '<span class="company">Company Name</span>',$content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```

и всё бы хорошо, если бы не картинки c подписью *alt*, которые надо обойти стороной, чтобы не сломалась вёрстка.
Как это можно сделать?

Дошёл до такого варианта, но он ещё не работает..

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'frost_the_content' );
function frost_the_content( $content ) {
$pattern = '~^(?!alt=".*Company Name.*"$)(Company Name)$~';
    return preg_replace($pattern, '<span class="nobr">Company Name</span>', $content);
    }
```

Comment: Я бы не советовал делать это в реалтайме. Лучше в базе поменять. Например с пом. https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Comment: @SeVlad а с `alt` как предлагаете решить вопрос? better-search-replace ведь заменит и внутри и запилите тег, а это поломает верстку. Ну и плюс задумка, чтобы сделать заплатку на постоянку, а не каждый n-времени проверять не добавилось ли новых мест для замены..

Comment: Конечно всё регулярками. Если не получится одной (я не готов с ходу утверждать что это можно), то  вторым проходом почистить альты. А советовал я к тому, что в твоё решение с реалтаймом будет создавать нагрузку. Не нужную по сути.

Comment: А вторая твоя проблема решается уже на моменте записи. Например хуком save_post.